# How to write a create() function in DRF serializer for a model with a many-to-many field by passing data through Axios, and Vue.js

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, axios, django-serializer

I have [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js) at the frontend and I'm using Axios to post user input to an API.

I have a Class model and a Student Model. In Student Model, I have a field named "classes" as a many-to-many field. Users will be able to input all the fields beside the *class.id* in the form (since I *class.id* can be retrieved using *$router.params*).

I want to create the Student instance and add this class instance called *clss* to its relation, *student.classes.add(clss)*. How am I supposed to implement the create() in the serializer class? I tried to come up with the following, but it seems not to be working.

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = (
            "id",
            "classes",
            "studentID",
            "lastName",
            "firstName",
            "gender",
            "dob",
            "ssn",
            "tel",
            "address",
            "email",
            "userName",
            "acctPass",
            "note"
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        clss = self.request.query_params['class_id']
        student = Student.objects.create(**validated_data)

        student.classes.add(clss)
        student.save()
        return student
```

In the AddStudent view, I have the following:

```
xport default {
    name: 'AddStudent',
    data(){
        return {
            clss:{},
            student:{}
        }
    },
    async mounted(){
        await this.getClass()
    },
    methods:{
        getClass(){
            const classID = this.$route.params.id
            axios
                .get(`/api/v1/classes/${classID}`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.clss = response.data
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
                })
        },

        submitForm(){
            const classID = this.$route.params.id
            axios
                .post("/api/v1/students/", this.student,
                    {params:
                        {class_id: classID,
                        }
                    }
                )
                .then(response => {
                    // redirect
                    this.$router.push({name:Class, params: { id: classID}})
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
                })
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

My viewset looks like this:

```
class StudentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
    queryset = Student.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        clssID = self.request.query_params['class_id']
        print(clssID)
        clss = Class.objects.get(pk=clssID)
        return self.queryset.filter(classes=clss)
```

Comment: Can you share the exact request data django receives?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    return Student.objects.create(**validated_data)
```